# Find lim of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence where $a_1 \in \mathbb{R} $ and $a_{n+1}=\left | a_n-2^{1-n} \right |,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*$
Find $\lim_{n \to +\infty }{a_n}$

Comment: You keep using that tag; I don't think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 4):

If $a_1$ is large and positive, the absolute value signs don't matter and the limit is just $a_1-2$.  If $a_1$ is negative, $a_2=-a_1+1$ and all the remaining operations are subtraction, so the limit is $-a_1$.  If $0 \le a_1 \lt 2$, each successive term is closer  zero and the limit is zero.  You need to convince yourself that the argument works.

Comment: Can you give me solutions? I thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you subtract $1$, then you subtract $1/2$, then you subtract $1/4$, and so on.

Ultimately, you are subtracting $2$ (do you see why?) and get $a_1 - 2$, with the only details omitted here occurring around what happens when the absolute value comes into play.

I leave this last piece to you, since this looks like homework anyway.